# XMM0 edit parts of [00] and [+04]

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, sse

```
newmem:
  movsd xmm0,[p_xyz]
code:
  movq [ecx+38],xmm0
  je flashplayer11_7r700_224_win_sa.exe+27845
  jmp return
p_xyz:
  dq (double)0
INJECT:
  jmp newmem
return:
```

Okay so, mine movq edits [00] and [+04] parts of xmm0 in same time...
I would like to edit [00] part and edit [04] part to what i would like.
xmm0 looks like this:

```
xmm0: 1973.66 - 295.23 - 68.30 - 0.00
```

I need to edit 1973.66 to what I would like with one command.
With second command I would like to edit 295.23 with another one command. So I could just go with movq after this.
So basically there is 4 dwords inside of xmm0. So I need to figure out how to overwrite first one and second one.

Comment: Fixed description. Thanks @harold

Comment: Memory source `movq`, `movsd`, or `movss` zero-extend into the full register.  If you want to modify just the low one or two elements, you can `movss` or `movsd` from another register. https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movss.   Or SSE4.1 `blendps`.  See the SIMD chapter in Agner Fog's asm optimization guide, https://agner.org/optimize/

Comment: I wish I could split those two first dwords items by variables and edit, as I would like to. All ideas are forcing me to overwrite both in same time...

Comment: To overwrite from a memory source operand, there's SSE4.1 `pinsrd` or (with a 128-bit source) `blendps`.  BTW, putting data next to code is normally a bad idea for performance.  *Especially* if you ever write that data: self-modifying code pipeline nuke.

Comment: Different dwords can also be loaded into differet regs and mixed with `punpck*` instructions, if for some reason cannot rely on SSE4.1

Comment: To overwrite the lower half of a xmm register, you can also use [`movlps`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movlps) (or `movlpd`) with a memory source. Maybe tell what you actually want to achieve ...